# Terracotta-server-not-starting-after-restart-activity

Tags: integration, webmethod, terracotta, webmethods

Terracotta used and 10.7 level:

We restarted our terracotta server but it’s not starting up after shutdown of server.
We are getting below error in wrapper logs.

```
INFO | jvm 1 | 2024/03/24 22:45:22 | Fatal Terracotta startup exception:
INFO | jvm 1 | 2024/03/24 22:45:22 |
INFO | jvm 1 | 2024/03/24 22:45:22 |
INFO | jvm 1 | 2024/03/24 22:45:22 | *******************************************************************************
INFO | jvm 1 | 2024/03/24 22:45:22 | You have specified server name ‘serverName’ which does not exist in the specified tc-config file.
INFO | jvm 1 | 2024/03/24 22:45:22 |
INFO | jvm 1 | 2024/03/24 22:45:22 | Please check your settings and try again.
```

The server was working fine 2 hours back.
We have checked the /etc/hosts file the hostname and ip are mapped correctly.
Also check that parameter.6 property is set to %Hostname% and changed it to server hostname but didn’t work.

Any support is highly appreciteated, it’s block multiple on going projects.

We tried to reconfigure our tc-config file and wrapper config file as well.

Could anyone support who has faced similar issue.